# how to run period job in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a job which want to run periodically, for example (assume I have a parameter named as `period` and the job is calculating total of logs):

```
# period=minutely
2017-07-17 16:01:00 total logs: 100
2017-07-17 16:02:00 total logs: 90
2017-07-17 16:03:00 total logs: 106
...
# period=hourly
2017-07-17 12:00:00 total logs: 63420
2017-07-17 13:00:00 total logs: 56218
2017-07-17 14:00:00 total logs: 80956
2017-07-17 15:00:00 total logs: 10846
2017-07-17 16:00:00 total logs: 209868
...
```

so how can I achieve this? I'm a green hand in `ruby`, any answers will be appreciated

Comment: Have you ever checked [this](https://github.com/javan/whenever) out?

Comment: yes, I have tried `whenever`, but how can I achieve this by using original `ruby` code? seems `whenever` is too heavy for us

Comment: If all you need is what you list above and your application runs under **Unix/Linux** environment, why don't you give `cron` a shot? any concern?

Comment: we want to embed this into source code

Answer (score 1):

Here is super simple and rough example of an *every 4 seconds* job.

```
$> vim whenever.rb
#!/bin/env ruby

job = -> (seconds, timer) {
  puts "Seconds #{seconds} Timer #{timer}"
}

timer = ARGV.first
loop do
  seconds = Time.now.sec
  if (seconds % timer.to_i).zero?
    job.call(seconds, timer)
  end
  sleep 1
end
$chmod +x whenever.rb 
$ ./whenever.rb 4
Seconds 28 Timer 4
Seconds 32 Timer 4
Seconds 36 Timer 4
^C./whenever.rb:13:in `sleep': Interrupt
```

If you're using Rails you can add an environment to your plain script and check the time.

```
#!/bin/env ruby

# If this file __FILE in the Rails 
# project root directory
require './config/environment'

job = -> (seconds, timer) {
  puts <<-MSG
  Seconds #{seconds} Timer #{timer} 
  Users #{User.count}  # Rails models
  Is it beginning of month #{Time.now.beginning_of_month}" # Rails helpers
  MSG
}
timer = ARGV.first
loop do
  seconds = Time.now.sec
  if (seconds % timer.to_i).zero?
    job.call(seconds, timer)
  end
  sleep 1
end
```

Comment: we do not use `cron`!  `whenever` is not suitable for us

Comment: There is no such thing like `cron` or [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever) in my answer, check it carefully.

Comment: sorry for that. if I run the script at `2017-07-17 16:32:00` and the period is an hour, it should be at `2017-07-17 17:32:00`,  but what I want is `2017-07-17 17:00:00`,  so how to achieve this